# Why would a PriorityQueue not act like a Queue?

Tags: java, stack, queue, priority-queue

I am using the `PriorityBlockingQueue` with a priority field. In my test I use `System#currentTime()` for priorities—the same priorities are obtained by the computer being so quick that the milliseconds are the same (or more like the milliseconds on a PC has a margin of error).

When the priorities are the same the queue acts as if it’s a stack, which seems strange. Is there an alternative to make the queue act as if it’s a normal queue (that is, FIFO rather than LIFO behavior) when the priorities of the elements are the same?

Answer (score 11):

> Operations on this class make no guarantees about the ordering of elements with equal priority. If you need to enforce an ordering, you can define custom classes or comparators that use a secondary key to break ties in primary priority values.

The `PriorityBlockingQueue` docs [themselves](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) tell you this, and how to get around it if you need to.

Comment: Saw the docs, but expected that there would already be a utility class for making a queue not a stack. If i put on the queue, it should go to the back and jump the queue if its a higher priority.

Comment: Why?  Most users use a `PriorityBlockingQueue` _with different priorities._

Comment: "No guarantees about the ordering of elements with equal priority."  That means it could act like a stack, it could act like a queue, it could behave completely randomly, it could depend on whether it's Tuesday or whether it's sunny outside.  _No guarantees._

Comment: Sorry my question was incorrectly phrased, I am looking for an alternative that will guarantee order when priority is equal (i.e a Queue at all times). Like a different utility from google or apache if there is one, and not needed to create FIFO classes with atomic long seq numbers.

Comment: Nope, no alternative.  You can write a wrapper around `PriorityBlockingQueue` that does the `AtomicLong` stuff internally, though.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think the priority queue guarantees the order of getting equal elements. One option is to have the priority more complex - push the negative of the size of the queue when pushing the element along with its priority and compare these values for equal priority elements.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a PriorityBlockingQueue with your own Comparator that takes creation time into account (see [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#PriorityBlockingQueue(int, java.util.Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#PriorityBlockingQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29) ).
You might have to change your keys from simple Date to a class of Date and counter, where the latter will get globally incremented with every creation (static field of your new key class); it's not really FIFO but rather First Created First Out.

Or, just implement your own PriorityQueueFifo class.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to maintain a counter in your tests that you use for the priority, and that you increase on each insertion. That way your priority queue will have FIFO ordering in your tests, yet it will look like an arbitrary priority queue.